# Взаимодействие контроллера и директивы в Angulsrjs

Tags: angularjs

Есть такая директива

```
app.directive('rootElement', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        controller:'rootElementController',
        templateUrl: undefined,
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) { 
            console.log(scope.testScope.pages[5]) 
            this.templateUrl = scope.testScope.pages[5];
        }
    }
});
```

Которая взаимодействует с неким контроллером и у последнего получает строку (**Путь вот в таком виде `frontend/pages/page-main/index.html`**), мне она нужна до того как я ее могу получить.  Это путь для `templateUrl`.

Могу ли я в функции `link` изменить значения `templateUrl`?

Пробовал как приведено в примере, но увы и ах (не получилось)...

Можно ли это как то реализовать?

После подсказки, реализовал так

```
app.directive('rootElement', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        controller:'rootElementController',
        templateUrl: '<ng-include src="{{testScope.pages[5]}}"></ng-include>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) { 

        }
    }
});
```

Но получаю ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`templateUrl` может быть функцией, но доступа к скоупу там не будет.

Вместо него можно использовать `ng-include` с интересующим тебя путём:

```
template: '<ng-include src="testScope.pages[5]"></ng-include>',
```

Comment: А больше, ни где ничего не нужно менять, так как у меня выдает ошибку

Comment: Откуда я знаю? Как минимум, код из link удалить.

Comment: Qwertiy, глянь вопрос, я его правил...

Comment: @Air, исправил. Скобки убери.

Comment: Qwertiy, благодарю... У меня тоже было ошибка,  `templateUrl` вместо `template`...